# What does duct tape refer to?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-team

Korneel Bouman is [listed as](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) *Duct Tape*. Whats that?

[image]

Comment: Now we just need a WD-40 employee (maybe a sysadmin, keeps things moving). Reference: http://johnmeister.com/engineering-flowchart.jpg

Comment: Seeing its been asked the second time, I dont think "too localized" again, is a good idea.

Comment: Duct tape is like the Force. It has a light side, a dark side, and it holds the universe together.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Korneel is a pro-**duct** manager at Stack Exchange.

That means he is holding together a bunch of programmers, requirements and stackholders, much like duct tape does with less animate objects (?).

Employees have the leeway to choose their own title, this is Korneel's little joke.

The (deleted) duplicate is at:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159104/what-is-the-duct-tape-position-at-the-stack-exchange-and-what-does-it-entail/159107#159107

Where Korneel says:

> Seriously though, we get to pick our own job titles, and while I could have gone for something swanky like Director of Customer Service and Sales Operations, Duct Tape seemed truer to the core of what I actually do.

Comment: Deleted dup .... :(

Comment: Another thing, how frequently is the team page updated? Its missing some people I think.

Comment: @AshRj - not all that often. Every couple of months or so, when enough newbs have come aboard.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя - "closed as too localized"...

Comment: "...much like duct tape does with less animate objects (?)." Duct tape holds together everything! Doesn't matter if animate or not.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - Was wondering who would be the first to comment on that ;)