# Does this mister really work for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

Today someone found this profile on twitter:

> https://twitter.com/olupotd

In his profile Bio it says:

> Uhh Lets see. All i can say is that I love being me and it's really cool. I love Discovery if you know what i mean **plus i work at Stackoverflow**. See you around.

His possible SO profile is [*this one*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2114557/olupot-douglas).

So the question is: does he really? (as a concerned citizen)

<sup>Bonus question: Does someone know what does he mean with "I love Discovery"?</sup>

Comment: The concerning question is: Why do you care?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, No! I've picked the person that happens to have a similar name, **links to the same twitter account** and have a very similar profile picture and named it *possible*.

Comment: @Xeo, just to make sure. Call it curiosity.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't really, but if one were to care, it might be because it seems unlikely this is an SE employee and as such he would be either wilfully or accidentally (through language barrier) misrepresenting his relationship with Stack Exchange Inc. I think most companies would object to random people falsely and publicly claiming an agreement of employment.

Comment: For the record I have politely asked the user to clarify their role within Stack Exchange Inc. (whilst pointing out delicately that the organisation with which they have allegedly entered into an agreement of employment, is not called "stackoverflow"). There is probably not much need for the Meta post unless he is not an employee and refuses to stop claiming to be.

Comment: When not even knowing that there's a space in the company name, I'd have my doubts too...

Comment: @Arjan: And `s/overflow/exchange/` Also, without trying to be rude, I think a recently departed election nominee [would have a better chance of employment here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21797538/560648) ;)

Comment: Maybe he meant to write "I am active on Stack Overflow"? (But then, he's not *very* active really.)

Comment: @Arjan: Agreed all. I think it's just an unfortunate error in wording. But still it's kind of weird to state it as a "job" in your FB profile, after just 11 months with only 53 rep

Comment: Haha, if he also mentioned it as a job elsewhere, then that's bad. Unless he's actually doing something in the team, of course. But then the company's introduction needs some improvements, @Lightness :-)

Comment: Bonus comment: [Discovery Channel](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters)?

Comment: What do you know, @Lightness, SE personnel [does *not* get to see the correct name](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stack+Exchange/@40.708793,-74.006756,3a,90y,153.08h,85.87t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sNI4VOv1ukYkAAAQIt-PqAQ!2e0!3e2!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xf9742bc540e39399)! (Unless they use a different entrance to their office.)

Comment: @Arjan: That's a stylised logo ;) Otherwise blame poor keming

Comment: Yeah, @Lightness, if it's a logo then who's to blame for forgetting the two different colors? ;-) (Also: wondering how much heat all those beamers in that office generate...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He is not on the team page: https://stackexchange.com/about/team, unless he changed his name and wears a cactus suit.

Also, given that he misspells Stack Overflow, and that any employee would say Stack *Exchange*, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know about that page. +1 (Wish my company would do that)

Comment: In theory, it [could take some time for folks to show up there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182024/what-does-duct-tape-refer-to#comment553953_182025). (I remember that it took some time for Oded to appear there.) But again, I agree this guy is probably not in the team.

Answer (score -10):

what is it with you guys. Honestly have you actually looked at my profile on SO? i have or had 53 Reputations and now it's close to 40. How can someone with such a number of reputations be a member of SO more so an employee? I ain't an employee and I accept any punishment you guys may have in mind for me but I'm just trying to build a good CV that's all and it has nothing to do with working for SO.

Comment: I assume you didn't mean *"I am faking my CV"*, but to me *"I'm just trying to build a good CV"* sounds like that (in the context of this very question). Care to rephrase or explain more?

Comment: Well, we like our community and your *"plus i work at Stackoverflow"* seems to refer to that community. That makes us curious.

Comment: If you want to build a good CV, I suggest filling it with facts, rather than misrepresentations. Both your Twitter profile and Facebook profile strongly indicate that you are a Stack Exchange employee, which you are not. If I worked at Stack Exchange (which I don't) I'm sure I wouldn't be too pleased about that.

Comment: ... the same is also going to apply to a future employer. Just sayin'

Comment: Huhh, okay does this make you feel better [here](https://twitter.com/olupotd)

Comment: My apologies for any inconveniences i may have caused. Deeply regrettable and won't happen again.

Comment: Liked the topic though. wonder who came up with it.

Comment: @OlupotDouglas If you want to show off your SO/SE participation you can use "flair"... Go to your user profile and click the "flair" link on the upper right side. It will give you some options for displaying your participation/achievements.

Comment: thanks I'll be sure to keep that in mind next time

Comment: Nice that you joined the conversation. From what I understood you had a poor choice of words when what you really want to promote in your CV is *`I participate at SO, etc`*. Taking a quick look at your profile, I'd suggest that you improve the quality of your Answers (see [answer]); this way you increase the recognition of your participation here (more reputation) and at the same time become more knowleadgeable on your field (more research, reading documentation, analyzing and writing code). I'm much better programmer after joining [se]. Good luck and best wishes :)

Comment: thanks @brasofilo thanks for the advise everyone. I guess i'll have to get more serious next time.